# vs 2015 с++ не компилирует

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Установил VS 2015, все хорошо, но хэлло ворлд не компилирует

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hello world";
    return 0;

}
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2065   'cout': undeclared identifier
>   ConsoleApplication2 c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp    9

У меня *Windows 7 x64*.

Answer (score 4):

Предложение

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

должно предшествовать всем другим заголовочным файлам, то есть предложениям с `#include`.

Напишите

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: вы просто волшебник! заработало! благодарю и счастливого Рождества